# Weather API does not load and threads keep suspending

Tags: android, api, android-asynctask

I was working on a weather app and I used openweather API to fetch weather data. 
For testing purpose, I fetched the API data and tried to print in logs but for some reason, it does not work and I keep getting this error:
[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcrFC.png)

Here is my java and xml file: [Code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/960f9a9fc49ee50e20e75b487ed19c69)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` loop will never stops because you are not updating the value of `data`

```
 data = isr.read();            // read and assign int to data
 while(data!=-1){              // not -1
     result += (char) data;    // add to result
     isr.read();               // read next 
     // data field value will never be updated inside loop ,hence infinite loop
   }
```

so change

```
 data = isr.read(); // read and assign char to data
 while(data!=-1){
     result += (char) data;
     data = isr.read();
     // data value will never be changes inside loop , infinite loop
   }
```

[Gist link for concise approach](https://gist.github.com/Pavneet-Sing/470b2d13d1b2987a0de4a84382b434fd)